# Android file upload by using HTML file input control

Tags: android, browser, upload, ram

I just want to ask if there is now a workaround to solve the file upload problem in Android when there's not enough RAM after file selection.

Look at these URLs:

[Android browser refreshes page after selecting file via input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274727/android-browser-refreshes-page-after-selecting-file-via-input-element)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53088

https://github.com/kostysh/File-uploading-component-for-Sencha-Touch/issues/5

My smart phone Samsung Galaxy xcover has 37,70 MB RAM.

When I click a standard HTML file upload control on a web page and select a file (from gallery, camera, camcorder etc.) Android kills the browser instance to get some free RAM, then Android starts the browser again and refreshes the web page.

I think there must be a technical solution some day ...

Has anybody new information about this problem?

Thomas

Comment: do you use webview for that

Comment: Hello Amit, what is "webview"?

Comment: i think you are not try with android project you test direct with browser am i right >

Comment: Hello Amit, the problem these people and I describe is a problem concerning standard HTML, Firefox and Android. I don't use any frameworks.

Comment: Hello Amit, we use Firefox and the other usual Android browsers. We need Firefox because it offers the phone camera as a file source. The photo file you shot will "return" to the browser and is uploaded with standard html,javascript and php.