# Instagram embedded browser refreshes page after uploading a picture (which is lost after that refresh)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, instagram, embedded-browser

I am facing a big issue for my project where basically nobody coming from Instagram browser cannot register, because after they upload mandatory image IG browser will reload the page (in normal browsers it works fine).

I even tried to simplify it to native html input - still happening. Also tried to put different attributes according to this question: [Mobile browser refreshes page after uploading a photo using Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191339/mobile-browser-refreshes-page-after-uploading-a-photo-using-camera) but without any success.

You can try it on public URL: https://meetymeety-af1lom2yv-smoothweb.vercel.app/Explore
(you need to send it in IG message and open via IG). As you can see the page will always refresh right after image upload.

Any solution for that?

*Note: We are using Next.js + React.js, but since these are just simple html inputs not connected to any state or whatever it has no effect on it.*

Comment: Are you using `event.preventdefault()` (see https://sebhastian.com/react-preventdefault/)?

Comment: @BillHorvath Of course that was one of the first things I tried, with no effect obviously. You can try it yourself, it's simply not fixing it.