# Vue PWA refreshing page when returning from camera app (Android)

Tags: android, vuejs3, android-camera, progressive-web-apps

I have a Vue 3 PWA app that has the ability to upload multiple photo's to an form. I use an input element with the type 'file' which defaults to the android stock camera. This post [Mobile browser refreshes page after uploading a photo using Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191339/mobile-browser-refreshes-page-after-uploading-a-photo-using-camera) mentions adding the capture tag to the input element which should 'solve' the problem. I've tried this solution, but this did not solve it.

The is the code from my input tag:

```
<input
  @change="onFileChange($event, undefined)"
  id="imageCapture"
  name="image"
  type="file"
  class="sr-only"
  capture
/>
```

The bug doesn't always happen, but it happens occasionaly.

I've tried locking orientation, adding the capture tag and changing the background process setting in the android developer settings.